# Smarter way to give out lowest value of ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, min, shortcode

at the moment I use the following function to give out the lowest number of a ACF field. The code is working but not the smartest and most resource conserving way.

```
add_shortcode( 'LEASINGFAKTOR', 'leaserate_shortcode' );
function leaserate_shortcode () {
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'fahrzeuge',
        'meta_key'      => 'leasingfaktor',
    );
    $low_rate_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    $rate = array();

    if( $low_rate_query->have_posts() ):
        while( $low_rate_query->have_posts() ) : $low_rate_query->the_post();
            $rate = get_field('leasingfaktor'); 
            if(isset($rate) && !empty($rate)){
                $rates[] = $rate; 
            }
        endwhile;
        $max_rate = max($rates);
        $min_rate = min($rates);

        endif; wp_reset_query();
        return $min_rate;
}
```

Any ideas on making it cleaner, faster, smarter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You can use `get_posts` instead of using `WP_Query` because you just need the array of post ids that you can use with `get_field`, and using `get_posts` you don't need to do a `while` loop, and `wp_reset_query`

Another improvement that you can do is to use, `array_map` instead of `foreach`  because you're not trying to generate any HTML here or not doing anything complex. you're just trying to get an array of `rates` so `array_map` is better in this case and easy to use and the code will be short.

So your final code using `get_posts` and `array_map` will be like this:

```
/**
 * Shortcode function
 */
function leaserate_shortcode() {
    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'fahrzeuge',
        'meta_key'       => 'leasingfaktor', // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.SlowDBQuery
        'fields'         => 'ids', // We just need ids for our work.
    );

    /**
     * We will use get_posts instead of using WP_Query
     * Because it's easy to use in this case and $no_found_rows
     * is set to false that will give fast performance
     */
    $post_ids = get_posts( $query_args );

    // Set default min rate.
    $min_rate = 0;

    // Check if we found ids or not.
    if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) ) {
        /**
         * We don't need to do foreach or for loop here
         * We can use an array map and map the post ids array
         * with the values.
         * So we will have an array of rates in the result
         */
        $rates = array_map(
            function( $id ) {
                // we use using type transform using (int)
                // assuming returning value will be a number or string number.
                return (int) get_field( 'leasingfaktor', $id );
            },
            $post_ids
        );

        // Filter empty values and get unique values.
        $rates = array_unique( array_filter( $rates ) );

        // Check if the final array is not empty.
        if ( ! empty( $rates ) ) {
            $min_rate = min( $rates );
        }
    }

    return $min_rate;
}
add_shortcode( 'LEASINGFAKTOR', 'leaserate_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Hey there,

thanks for explaining each step so well! Unfortunatly it's not working as expected. If you cehck e.g. here: https://moinmobility.de/marken/vw/.

The min leaserate should be 0.50, but the code prints out 0.

How can I fix that? :)

Comment: I can't debug the code since I don't have your setup. You can use the `print_r` function and check the values you're getting and where is code logic is failing. as you mentioned you are expecting `0.50` so I think you're using a float, you can see I have used `(int)` for type transform, so you can use `(float)` there if that doesn't work then you can remove it and apply other checks as per requirement and your data setup.

Comment: Yes, works perfecly now! Thanks again :) The icing on the cake would now be if I could output the result as 0.5 instead of 0.5.

How would that be possible and what do I need to edit? :)

Comment: if you're talking about (.) dot at the end then it comes to your elementor text. not from a shortcode.

Comment: No, talking about the dot between 0 and zero. In Europe you split decimal numbers with a comma not a dot. So I would like to transform the dot into a comma.